# Arduino - Appending loop count to int name

Tags: loops, arduino

How do I append the loop number [x] to the variable name [Var]

All the [int Val]'s have been populated from previous code.

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++)

   if (Val[x] > 3){

      Serial.println("Do something");

   }

}
```

Comment: you don't use variables, you use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Got my reply from the Arduino forum.

I put the values into an array then used the following code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < (sizeof(Val) / sizeof(Val[0])); x++) {
   if (Val [i]  > 3){
      Serial.println("Do something");
   }
}
```